# What game uses six-sided dice with symbols as well as numbers on the 5 and 6 faces and a blank space where “1” should be?

Tags: dice, product-identification

Note for reviewers, this question is a part of several similar questions. It has been broken down so as to not run afoul of other guidelines. Whilst they are almost identical, they are not duplicates of each other as they are asking about identifying different dice. This means that, whilst the questions are similar, they are not the same. Also, as they are each asking to identify different dice, the answers to each question will be vastly different, thusly they are not duplicates.

For readers, if you have already read another part of this series of questions, feel free to skip the text as it is identical, the only section you would need to focus on is the pictures themselves.

For reference, here are the rest of the questions in this series:

[What game uses dice with cyborg skulls in place of the 1 symbol?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149755/what-game-uses-dice-with-cyborg-skulls-in-place-of-the-1-symbol)

[What game uses glitter-filled dice with an arrow-like symbol with bracket-like symbols either side of it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149758/what-game-uses-glitter-filled-dice-with-an-arrow-like-symbol-with-bracket-like-s)

[What game uses six-sided dice with symbols as well as numbers on the 5 and 6 faces?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149738/what-game-uses-six-sided-dice-with-symbols-as-well-as-numbers-on-the-5-and-6-fac)

[What game uses dice with engraved faces, weapon symbols, double weapon symbols and object symbols?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149753/what-game-uses-dice-with-engraved-faces-weapon-symbols-double-weapon-symbols-a)

[What game uses dice with compass point arrows, forbidden signs, explosions, arrows and targeting reticles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149747/what-game-uses-dice-with-compass-point-arrows-forbidden-signs-explosions-arro)

---

A while ago I bought a few bags of factory 2nd dice. Out of those bags, there are a handful of dice that I have not been able to immediately identify. Some I have later been able to identify through image searching, such as the Warhammer Blood Angels, Adeptus Mechanicus and Tyranids logo dice, as well as the green and pink nebular swirl dice.

However, I am still unsure as to what some of the dice are. I’ve tried looking at dice websites, searching on Google and even using reverse image searches, all to no avail. For some, I am not even sure how to concisely describe them to accurately search for them.

What I want to know is what game are these dice from? Or, if they are not from a specific game, what they are called. Below are images of the dice:

[image]

Comment: @Skathix please, do not answer (not  even partially) in the comments. The comments are for clarifying and improving the post only. Answers in the comments section will be removed by the community, so please, if you have a valid complete answer move it to the answer section. See [this post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for our policy. Thanks!

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I have edited the question as per your recommendations. I also have a note at the top just to try avoid any future complications. However, before you advised “to not post them all at the same time necessarily”, how long would you recommend I wait in between asking these question? I do not wish to flood the front page of the site with these questions.

Comment: Your edits look great! I (and a couple people from chat) seem to think that giving maybe 5-30 minutes should be good. There's no rules (that I know of) against posting time, just trying to help avoid potential downvotes (for doing the correct thing).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The logo on the dice is the [Shadowrun](https://wuerfel-stube.de/media/image/product/4189/lg/shadowrun-schattenwuerfel-set-rot~2.jpg) logo. Those dice are for the Shadowrun RPG.

The game itself uses a result of 5 or 6 as a "hit", a result of 2 to 4 as a "nothing" and a result of 1 as a "glitch", and in some cases a 6 is better than a 5 (similar to a critical hit).  This is consistent with how your dice are marked (Shadowrun logo means "hit", nothing at all means "glitch", but 5 of the 6 numbers are still marked for when they are needed, or in case you need regular six-sided dice.)

Comment: Shadowrun also sometimes uses 'exploding 6es' (additional rolling of all dice that showed 6), so it's necessary to be able to distinguish 5 and 6.

Comment: also, this type of dice is only used since 4th edition - 1st to 3rd edition had shifting "hit" results.