# What game uses dice with compass point arrows, forbidden signs, explosions, arrows and targeting reticles?

Tags: dice, product-identification

Note for reviewers, this question is a part of several similar questions. It has been broken down so as to not run afoul of other guidelines. Whilst they are almost identical, they are not duplicates of each other as they are asking about identifying different dice. This means that, whilst the questions are similar, they are not the same. Also, as they are each asking to identify different dice, the answers to each question will be vastly different, thusly they are not duplicates.

For readers, if you have already read another part of this series of questions, feel free to skip the text as it is identical, the only section you would need to focus on is the pictures themselves.

For reference, here are the rest of the questions in this series:

[What game uses dice with cyborg skulls in place of the 1 symbol?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149755/what-game-uses-dice-with-cyborg-skulls-in-place-of-the-1-symbol)

[What game uses glitter-filled dice with an arrow-like symbol with bracket-like symbols either side of it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149758/what-game-uses-glitter-filled-dice-with-an-arrow-like-symbol-with-bracket-like-s)

[What game uses six-sided dice with symbols as well as numbers on the 5 and 6 faces?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149738/what-game-uses-six-sided-dice-with-symbols-as-well-as-numbers-on-the-5-and-6-fac)

[What game uses dice with engraved faces, weapon symbols, double weapon symbols and object symbols?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149753/what-game-uses-dice-with-engraved-faces-weapon-symbols-double-weapon-symbols-a)

[What game uses dice with compass point arrows, forbidden signs, explosions, arrows and targeting reticles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149747/what-game-uses-dice-with-compass-point-arrows-forbidden-signs-explosions-arro)

---

A while ago I bought a few bags of factory 2nd dice. Out of those bags, there are a handful of dice that I have not been able to immediately identify. Some I have later been able to identify through image searching, such as the Warhammer Blood Angels, Adeptus Mechanicus and Tyranids logo dice, as well as the green and pink nebular swirl dice.

However, I am still unsure as to what some of the dice are. I’ve tried looking at dice websites, searching on Google and even using reverse image searches, all to no avail. For some, I am not even sure how to concisely describe them to accurately search for them.

What I want to know is what game are these dice from? Or, if they are not from a specific game, what they are called. Below are images of the dice:

[image]

I also have green and purple dice similar to the ones in the above image.

[This question has also been asked over at BG.SE](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47527/what-game-uses-dice-with-compass-point-arrows-forbidden-signs-explosions-arro)

Comment: One side of the dice is not shown, the one opposite to the explosion. What is it?

Comment: @Zachiel It is shown, there are explosions on either side, you see :b

Comment: @LiamMorris are the orange dice different from the white dice, or are they identical? (other than color, of course)

Comment: I have a vague sense that these are from a board game involving fighting robots, but I can't track down which game I'm thinking of. Might be worth cross-posting to the board games stack.

Comment: I found an image showing the same dice online [here](http://dicecollector.com/images/small/9b/bc29fa41179ba945698429ba38b304.jpg), but the the context on the hosting site only indicate that the hoster believes they're Warhammer/scatter dice of some kind, which may not be accurate.

Answer (score 16):

From user [Glazius](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/19405/glazius) over at Boardgames.SE:

These are [survivor dice](http://dicecollector.com/images/large/45/3c11f75fdbfe886d4a78294dd2d550.jpg) from the cooperative world-of-survival-horror board game [Dark, Darker, Darkest](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/59429/dark-darker-darkest).

(The picture is labeled as "an expansion", but it's just a set of dice in each of the player colors. The base game uses these dice but shares a set among players.)

[image: images of the dice and the box they're sold in]

[Here is a link to Glazius’ answer on Boardgames.SE](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/47529/27594)