# What game uses dice with cyborg skulls in place of the 1 symbol?

Tags: dice, product-identification

Note for reviewers, this question is a part of several similar questions. It has been broken down so as to not run afoul of other guidelines. Whilst they are almost identical, they are not duplicates of each other as they are asking about identifying different dice. This means that, whilst the questions are similar, they are not the same. Also, as they are each asking to identify different dice, the answers to each question will be vastly different, thusly they are not duplicates.

For readers, if you have already read another part of this series of questions, feel free to skip the text as it is identical, the only section you would need to focus on is the pictures themselves.

For reference, here are the rest of the questions in this series:

[What game uses dice with cyborg skulls in place of the 1 symbol?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149755/what-game-uses-dice-with-cyborg-skulls-in-place-of-the-1-symbol)

[What game uses glitter-filled dice with an arrow-like symbol with bracket-like symbols either side of it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149758/what-game-uses-glitter-filled-dice-with-an-arrow-like-symbol-with-bracket-like-s)

[What game uses six-sided dice with symbols as well as numbers on the 5 and 6 faces?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149738/what-game-uses-six-sided-dice-with-symbols-as-well-as-numbers-on-the-5-and-6-fac)

[What game uses dice with engraved faces, weapon symbols, double weapon symbols and object symbols?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149753/what-game-uses-dice-with-engraved-faces-weapon-symbols-double-weapon-symbols-a)

[What game uses dice with compass point arrows, forbidden signs, explosions, arrows and targeting reticles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149747/what-game-uses-dice-with-compass-point-arrows-forbidden-signs-explosions-arro)

---

A while ago I bought a few bags of factory 2nd dice. Out of those bags, there are a handful of dice that I have not been able to immediately identify. Some I have later been able to identify through image searching, such as the Warhammer Blood Angels, Adeptus Mechanicus and Tyranids logo dice, as well as the green and pink nebular swirl dice.

However, I am unsure as to what these dice are. I’ve tried looking at dice websites, searching on Google and even using reverse image searches, all to no avail.

What I want to know is what game are these dice from? Or, if they are not from a specific game, what they are called. Below are images of the dice:

[image]

Comment: Do you have reason to believe they belong to a tabletop roleplaying game? Otherwise you might have more luck asking this question over at [boardgames.se]

Comment: @Erik I would have assumed they are, however i have been advised in [chat] that i should cross-post there to see if they’d have an answer. Edit: Though it does seem like I have my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They appear to be the [Cybo Skull dice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCykEgkGuwI), produced as a novelty dice set for no game in particular. The box describes them as "unique dice", which suggests that they were only ever made for this set.

It's no longer sold by its manufacturer, em4miniatures. They appear to have discontinued the Cybo Skull dice box, which may explain why remaining Cybo Skull dice appeared in a bag of factory seconds.