# What game uses glitter-filled dice with an arrow-like symbol with bracket-like symbols either side of it?

Tags: dice, product-identification

Note for reviewers, this question is a part of several similar questions. It has been broken down so as to not run afoul of other guidelines. Whilst they are almost identical, they are not duplicates of each other as they are asking about identifying different dice. This means that, whilst the questions are similar, they are not the same. Also, as they are each asking to identify different dice, the answers to each question will be vastly different, thusly they are not duplicates.

For readers, if you have already read another part of this series of questions, feel free to skip the text as it is identical, the only section you would need to focus on is the pictures themselves.

For reference, here are the rest of the questions in this series:

[What game uses dice with cyborg skulls in place of the 1 symbol?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149755/what-game-uses-dice-with-cyborg-skulls-in-place-of-the-1-symbol)

[What game uses glitter-filled dice with an arrow-like symbol with bracket-like symbols either side of it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149758/what-game-uses-glitter-filled-dice-with-an-arrow-like-symbol-with-bracket-like-s)

[What game uses six-sided dice with symbols as well as numbers on the 5 and 6 faces?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149738/what-game-uses-six-sided-dice-with-symbols-as-well-as-numbers-on-the-5-and-6-fac)

[What game uses dice with engraved faces, weapon symbols, double weapon symbols and object symbols?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149753/what-game-uses-dice-with-engraved-faces-weapon-symbols-double-weapon-symbols-a)

[What game uses dice with compass point arrows, forbidden signs, explosions, arrows and targeting reticles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149747/what-game-uses-dice-with-compass-point-arrows-forbidden-signs-explosions-arro)

---

A while ago I bought a few bags of factory 2nd dice. Out of those bags, there are a handful of dice that I have not been able to immediately identify.

What I want to know is what game are these dice from? Or, if they are not from a specific game, what they are called. Below are images of the dice:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### These are Harlequin dice, from Warhammer 40K

The symbol shown on the die is the Eldar rune associated with the [Harlequins](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Harlequin). The dice were originally put out by Games Workshop as a tin of 10 with a mix of yellow, blue, and red tinted dice, which matches up with the examples you have. Image found by way of [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Warhammer40k/comments/2xarys/new_harlequin_dice_are_just_as_sexy_as_advertised/):

[image: Games Workshop Harlequin dice tin]

They don't have any special purpose compared to other d6s in the game, they're just branded for the faction.